# Identify odd, even numbers - binary vs. mod

Tags: c#, performance

Recently I had to identify whether a number is odd or even for a large number of integers. I thought of an idea to identify a number as odd or even by AND-ing it against 1 and comparing the result to 1

```
x & 1 == 1 // even or odd
```

I have never seen this implementation in practice. The most common way you always see is :

```
x % 2 == 0
```

I decided to do some performance check on both methods and the binary method seems slightly faster on my machine.

```
int size = 60000000;
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    numberList.Add(rnd.Next(size));
}

DateTime start;
bool even;

// regular mod
start = DateTime.Now;
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    even = (numberList[index] % 2 == 0);
}
Console.WriteLine("Regualr mod : {0}", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Ticks);

// binary 
start = DateTime.Now;
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    even = ((numberList[index] & 1) != 1);
}
Console.WriteLine("Binary operation: {0}", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Ticks);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Has anyone seen the binary method implemented ? Any drawbacks ?

Comment: "I have never seen this implementation in practice".  You need to read more code.

Comment: You didn't state your results, but using DateTime for such a measurement is not likely to be sufficiently accurate.

Comment: It's really weird that binary is performing better. I am not arguing your experiments, but I would think **MOD** operation should be faster...

Comment: I doubt the difference matters in any real application. If you're executing database queries or talking across a network, those operations will take millennia compared to this simple integral operation.

Comment: You should be using the `StopWatch` class to do your benchmarks ;)

Comment: Note that the bitwise test won't work with negative numbers on a 1's complement machine. Not that that's a big concern, since, should you come across such a beast, I doubt it will have a C# compiler that can target it. Also, I don't know of anything in the C# standard that specifies the underlying representation for signed integers, but signed integer ranges all suggest 2's complement.

Comment: Also note the [*negative dividend pitfall*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls).

Comment: I have coded in C on a Cyber and it was a consideration. Mod should never be faster, the compiler should use bitwise "AND" on unsigned integers anyway in the same way initialising a var as zero should be an XOR against itself.  Mod complexity can depend upon architecture as well (arm has hardware smarts). It pays to read the disassembly in any case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, yes, it is a slight optimization.  This code snippet:

```
        uint ix = 3; // uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool even = ix % 2 == 0;
```

generates this machine code in the release build:

```
            uint ix = 3;
0000003c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],3 
            bool even = ix % 2 == 0;
00000043  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000046  and         eax,1 
00000049  test        eax,eax 
0000004b  sete        al   
0000004e  movzx       eax,al 
00000051  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
```

Do note that the JIT compiler is smart enough to use the AND processor instruction.  It is not doing a division as the % operator would normally perform.  Kudos there.

But your custom test generates this code:

```
        uint ix = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
// Bunch of machine code
        bool even = (ix & 1) == 0;
00000024  test        eax,1 
00000029  sete        al   
0000002c  movzx       eax,al 
0000002f  mov         esi,eax
```

I had to alter the assignment statement because the JIT compiler got suddenly smart and evaluated the expression at compile time.  The code is *very* similar but the AND instruction got replaced by a TEST instruction.  Saving one instruction in the process.  Fairly ironic how it this time chose to *not* use an AND :)

These are the traps of making assumptions.  Your original instinct was right however, it ought to save about half a nanosecond.  *Very* hard to see that back unless this code lives in a very tight loop.  It gets drastically different when you change the variable from uint to int, the JIT compiler then generates code that tries to be smart about the sign bit.  Unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

For such operations you should prefer the more readable approach (in my opinion the modulo-way) over the one that is thought to be faster.

Moreover, the modulo operation above can be optimized by the compiler into the bitwise-and operation. Therefore, you actually don't need to care.

Note to your example: To get more-precise results consider passing the number of items to be added into the list's constructor. This way you avoid discrepancies introduced by multiple reallocation of the backing array. For 60 million integer items (approc. 240 MB of memory) not preallocating the memory can represent a significant bias.

Comment: Good point on passing the size of an array. I made this improvement in the second version.

Comment: I also agree that Mod check is way more readable than the bitwise, I was only checking the performance out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise and will beat modulo division every day of the week. Division by an arbitrary number takes a lot of clock cycles, whereas bitwise and is an essential primitive op that almost always completes in 1 clock cycle, regardless of your CPU architecture.

What you may be seeing, though, is that the compiler may be replacing `x mod 2` with a bit shift or bit mask instruction which will have identical performance to your own bit mask operation.

To confirm that the compiler is playing tricks with your code, compare the performance of x mod 2 with x mod 7 or any other non-base 2 integer.  *Or* obscure the operands from the compiler so that it cannot perform the optimization:

```
var y = 2;
result = x mod y;
```

If you see a dramatic difference in execution time with these changes, then that's a pretty strong indicator that the compiler is treating `x mod 2` as a special case and not using actual division to find the remainder.

And if you're going to use DateTime to benchmark single-instruction operations, make sure you have a long enough loop that the test runs at least 5 minutes or so to get your true measurement above the noise floor.

Comment: Whoha! *"(...) at least 5 minutes"*?! Are you trying to be sarcasticly funny or are you being serious?

Comment: I'm serious.  If you're going to use a wall clock to measure time, make sure you use a long enough interval to watch the hands of the clock move.  DateTime is a poor way to benchmark execution times.

Answer (score 1):

[This webpage](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even) benchmarks at least half a dozen ways to determine whether a number is odd or even.

The fastest was (which I like for easy readability):

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
    //even number
else
    //odd number
```

Here were others tested ([code is here](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even)). I'm actually surprised the bitwise and bit shifting operations didn't perform the best:

```
//bitwise
if ((x & 1) == 0)
    //even number
else
    //odd number


System.Math.DivRem((long)x, (long)2, out outvalue);
if ( outvalue == 0)
    //even number
else
    //odd number


if (((x / 2) * 2) == x)
    //even number
else
    //odd number


//bit shifting
if (((x >> 1) << 1) == x)
    //even number
else
    //odd number


index = NumberOfNumbers;
while (index > 1)
    index -= 2;
if (index == 0)
    //even number
else
    //odd number


tempstr = x.ToString();
index = tempstr.Length - 1;
//this assumes base 10
if (tempstr[index] == '0' || tempstr[index] == '2' || tempstr[index] == '4' || tempstr[index] == '6' || tempstr[index] == '8')
    //even number
else
    //odd number
```

Comment: Bitwise `&` is much faster here (ca 15%), so I guess that it heavily depends on the runtime (.NET Framework vs .NET Core). And yes, it was a release build.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the binary method be faster because the compiler is able to optimize this into a bitshift rather than actually forcing the cpu to perform the division calculation?

Comment: One would think so but according to the benchmarks and code provided by @user3810913 it doesn't appear to always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers, that you should use the modulo check, because it best conveys intent.

However, for your specific results; try using the `even` variable. It will make a significant difference, because the compiler might actually optimize away some of the calculations because it knows it won't need to use the value.

Using your program (modified to use Stopwatch), I get 70 ms for regular mod and 88 ms for the binary operation. If I use the `even` variable, the difference is much smaller (327 vs 316 ms), and the modulos is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

For unsigned numbers, many compilers will optimize the 'mod' operator as an 'and' test.  For signed numbers, (x % 2) will be 1 if the number is odd and positive; -1 if it's odd and negative; even though both +1 and -1 are non-zero, they may not get recognized as equivalent.

BTW, when using the "and" operator, I would test for !=0 rather than ==1.  Compilers may recognize the equivalence, but they may not.